# Toggle plot visibility of dynamic number of data sets

Tags: plotting, manipulate, dynamic

I have multiple curves in my plot, and want to be able to toggle their visibility off/on.
Which I got to work thanks to a different post.

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 5}, {0, 6}};
Manipulate[ListPlot[data,
Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {-1, 5},
PlotStyle -> {Opacity[a], Opacity[b], Opacity[c]}],
{{a, 1, "f1"}, {1, 0}}, {{b, 1, "f2"}, {1, 0}}, {{c, 1, "f3"}, {1, 0}}]
```

My dataset is not always of the same dimensions though. So depending on the data loaded I might have only two graphs next time I run my notebook.

```
data= {{1, 3}, {0, 2}}
```

Is there a nice way to make my code automatically adjust to the number of graphs?

I think i could make this work using `Table` and `Length[data]`, but it feels as if there is a simpler and nicer way.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: The number of flags is dependent of `Length[data]`,so you'll need to use it either explicitly or implicitly

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Closely related: [(11073)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11073)

Comment: @ybeltukov I am not reading carefully; how is this one distinct from that one?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard (11073) is about toggling 3 curves exactly. The main point of this one is the variable number of curves.

Comment: also related: [How to dynamically toggle curves on/off in a crowded Plot?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20112/125)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up list of opacities automatically

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 5}, {0, 6}};
Manipulate[ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {-1, 5}, 
  PlotStyle -> (Opacity@Boole@MemberQ[x, #] & /@ Range@Length@data)], 
    {{x, {1}}, Dynamic@Range@Length@data, ControlType -> TogglerBar}]
```

[image]

Comment: This has the disadvantage that if you copy the figure for use elsewhere it stores all the data of invisible plots. ;-)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries You can add `/. {___, _@_Opacity, ___} -> {}` after the `ListPlot` :-)

Comment: This is it! Perfect, thank you! Both suggested solutions work. I preferred this one, since it's loading all graphs simultaneously and only toggles their opacity. I'm hoping this way is a bit faster when working with a lot of graphs at the same time. Thanks again to both of you!

Comment: I'd love to vote both of you up, but can't yet due to missing reputation.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 5}, {0, 6}};
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[data[[x]], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {-1, 5}], 
 {{x, {1}}, Range@Length@data, ControlType -> TogglerBar}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With more togglers toggled:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With differently size `data`

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 5}};
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[data[[x]], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {-1, 5}], 
 {{x, {1}}, Range@Length@data, ControlType -> TogglerBar}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Colors depend on the choice of curves...

Comment: @ybeltukov If that would really be a problem one could add `PlotStyle -> (ColorData[1, #] &) /@ x` or whatever color scheme one woulkd like to use.