# TogglerBar with arbitrary dimensions

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I'd like to split my `TogglerBar` into several rows, with it's length given in a list.

I found the `Appearance` options, but they only allow one fixed horizontal/vertical dimension. Which is why I thought splitting my `TogglerBar` up in several pieces would be the way to go.

```
data = {2, 3, 1}
Manipulate[Boole @ MemberQ[x, #] & /@ Range@Total @ data,
{x, {1, 2}, ControlType -> TogglerBar},
{x, {3, 4, 5}, ControlType -> TogglerBar},
{x, {6}, ControlType -> TogglerBar}]
```

How can I write this, so that it'll still work when I change the length of `data`? E.g. to `data = {1, 1, 2, 2}`.

Comment: Sorry about that! So currently I'm getting 3 TogglerBars with the length 2, 3 respectively 1, as given by the list `data`. This list is not always going to be the same though. So I'd like to write Manipulate in a way, that I can have any `data`I want and get a number of toggler bars given by the number of elements in `data`, with the number of togglers given by the numbers in `data`. Please let me know if it's still confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
data = {1, 1, 2, 2};

DynamicModule[{max = Tr @ data, x},
  Manipulate[
    Normal @ SparseArray[Thread[x -> 1], max],
    ##
  ] & @@
    Thread[{x, Internal`PartitionRagged[Range@max, data], 
    ControlType -> TogglerBar}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is it! Can I ask another question though? I was using the output of `manipulate` to change the opacity of a number of graphs in my `ListPlot`in order to toggle their visibility. I'm not that advanced with Mathematica yet and have a hard time implementing your code into what I wanted to achieve. Could you help me get into the right direction? [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71718/toggle-plot-visibility-of-dynamic-number-of-data-sets/71725#71725 "Link") is what I was going for. I was now trying to break my `ToggleBar` into several parts.

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Jason Good.  Sorry I wasn't around sooner to help, but working through it yourself was probably a better learning experience anyway.

Comment: Can I ask, I'd love to learn the more advanced language Syntax using @, @@, #&, /@ etc. I found a [stackexchange post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616) where their meanings are listed. Do you know if there are any tutorials on this? Or is there a way to practice their usage, or see examples where they are used in a well written way?

Comment: @Jason There is no short-cut to learning the language in my opinion.  In that post each of the operators has a **[ref]** link that will take you to its documentation page.  If you prefer a more linear tutorial I recommend [Leonid's online book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/Book.html) but I warn you that despite the name "introduction" it is quite thorough.  Other than these general guidelines anything I can think to point you toward would be more specific, such as my own answer to [(46238)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46238/121).

Comment: I'll work through these. Thanks for the advice!