# Issue with a Manipulate expression for showing points sets and the alpha shape enclosing them

Tags: manipulate

I am using the alphaShapes2DC function from this post. It is a module which contains a Quiet operation.
[DelaunayMesh in a specified closed region - creating a concave hull from a set of points](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88752/delaunaymesh-in-a-specified-closed-region-creating-a-concave-hull-from-a-set-o/88769#88769)

I have a list containing 14 lists of 2d-points

```
prjs = {{{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {5, 1}}, {{2,2}}, ..., {{1, 5}, {6, 5}, {3, 5}}}
```

with some sublists containing only one element and some duplicates so that the alphaShapes2DC function cannot run on such sublists.

I want to create a Manipulate function to display several sublists (with their polygon) at the same time.

```
Manipulate[
  If[Length @ prjs[[i]] > 2,
     Show[
       ListPlot[prjs[[i]], 
         Joined -> False, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[i]]], 
       RegionPlot[Evaluate[alphaShapes2DC[DeleteDuplicates @ prjs[[i]], 6]],
         PlotStyle -> {ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[i]], Opacity@.2}, 
         BoundaryStyle -> {ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[i]], Thin}, 
         PlotRange -> All], PlotRange -> {{-15, 10}, {-10, 10}}],
       ListPlot[prjs[[i]], 
         Joined -> False,
         PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[i]],
         PlotRange -> {{-15, 10}, {-20, 20}}]],
  {{i, 1}, Range @ Length @ prjs}, 
    ContinuousAction -> True, ControlType -> TogglerBar]
```

Running this code first shows what I want.

[image]

But it turns bad when I click on a number in the bar — the polygon disappears.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Revision

First I contrive some test data since you did't provide any,

```
SeedRandom[3];
Block[{size},
  size := RandomInteger[{1, 20}];
  pts = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {#, 2}] & /@ Table[size, 14]];
```

Now I generate lists for the items that will be plotted according to the buttons pressed on the toggler bar.

```
hullPlots = 
  Table[
    If[Length @ pts[[i]] > 2, 
      RegionPlot[ConvexHullMesh[pts[[i]]], 
        PlotStyle -> {ColorData[97][i], Opacity @ .2}, 
        BoundaryStyle -> {ColorData[97][i], Thin}], 
      Graphics[]], 
    {i, Length @ pts}];

ptPlots =
  Table[ListPlot[pts[[i]], PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][i]], {i, Length @ pts}];
```

Finally I write a `Manpulate` expression with a toggler bar control. The important thing to note about a toggler bar is that it returns a ***list*** of the buttons currently pressed.

```
DynamicModule[{hulls, pts},
  Manipulate[
    hulls = hullPlots[[selctn]];
    pts = ptPlots[[selctn]];
    Show[##, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}] & @@
      Join[hulls, pts],
    {{selctn, {1}, "i"}, Range @ Length @ ptPlots, TogglerBar}]]
```

The `Manpulate` expression comes up looking like this.

[image: initial]

And here is what it might look like with several buttons pressed.

[image: many]

Note: If there are problems with `alphaShapes2DC`, I think that is an issue for a separate question, and I don't want to deal with it. That is why I used `ConvexHullMesh` instead.

BTW, if you would prefer all the points to always be displayed, that can be done with even simpler code. Like so.

```
DynamicModule[{hulls, pts},
  Manipulate[
    hulls = hullPlots[[selctn]];
    Show[##, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}] & @@
      Join[hulls, ptPlots],
    {{selctn, {1}, "i"}, Range @ Length @ ptPlots, TogglerBar}]]
```

[image: all_pts]

Comment: Dear m_goldberg. Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it does not work as I need. I need a TogglerBar to display several sublists at the same time (my code was already working with a SetterBar). I took your code and change to TogglerBar and I get exactly the same issue : selecting one sublist make the polygon disappear and selecting two or more sublists is leading to a RegionPlot crash.

Comment: Based on your code, I try to run this simplest one with a TogglerBar and don't understand why it does not work : SeedRandom[3]; Block[{size}, size := RandomInteger[{10, 20}]; 
 pts = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {#, 2}] & /@ 
   Table[size, 14]]; Manipulate[
 Show[ListPlot[pts[[i]]], 
  RegionPlot[ConvexHullMesh[pts[[i]]]]], {{i, 1}, Range@Length@pts, 
  TogglerBar}]

Comment: I just want to do something like this : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71718/toggle-plot-visibility-of-dynamic-number-of-data-sets/71722#71722

Comment: Even this one does not work : SeedRandom[3]; Block[{size}, size := RandomInteger[{10, 20}]; 
 pts = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {#, 2}] & /@ 
   Table[size, 14]]; Manipulate[
 ConvexHullMesh@pts[[i]], {{i, 1}, Range@Length@pts, TogglerBar}] while it works with replacing ConvexHullMesh by ListPlot

Comment: @Porty. I have revised my answer to use a toggler bar. I hope it is now gives you a framework that you can use to work with `alphaShapes2DC`.

Comment: Perfect. Works great!